# ORA-02291: Integrity constraint Error Message in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

This is the information I am trying to insert to create :

```sql
insert into PHYSICIAN
(PH_Person_ID, Physician_Pager_Number, Physician_DEA_Number)
values ('12123', '9174578962', 'MR06224');

insert into PHYSICIAN
(PH_Person_ID, Physician_Pager_Number, Physician_DEA_Number)
values ('12124', '3478955521', 'MP08175');

insert into PHYSICIAN
(PH_Person_ID, Physician_Pager_Number, Physician_DEA_Number)
values ('12125', '6466458877', 'ML08617');

insert into PHYSICIAN
(PH_Person_ID, Physician_Pager_Number, Physician_DEA_Number)
values ('12126', '9173312459', 'ML07835');

insert into PHYSICIAN
(PH_Person_ID, Physician_Pager_Number, Physician_DEA_Number)
values ('12127', '3479912460', 'ML04696');

insert into PHYSICIAN
(PH_Person_ID, Physician_Pager_Number, Physician_DEA_Number)
values ('12128', '6461099841', 'MK12376');

Select *
From PHYSICIAN;
```

and

```sql
INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER 
(VO_Person_ID, INTEREST_ID)
VALUES(12333,'00001');

INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER 
(VO_Person_ID, INTEREST_ID)    
VALUES(23444, '00002');

INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER 
(VO_Person_ID, INTEREST_ID)    
VALUES(34555, '00003');

INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER 
(VO_Person_ID, INTEREST_ID)    
VALUES(45666, '00004');

INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER
(VO_Person_ID, INTEREST_ID)    
VALUES(56777, '00005');

INSERT INTO VOLUNTEER
(VO_Person_ID, INTEREST_ID)    
VALUES(67888, '00006');

SELECT *
FROM VOLUNTEER;
```

and

```sql
insert into CREDIT_CARD
(CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER,OWNER_NAME, MERCHANT_NAME, EXP_DATE)
values ('4100587464519954','Fawn Arleme','HSBC','14-FEB-2020');

insert into Credit_Card
(CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER,OWNER_NAME, MERCHANT_NAME, EXP_DATE)
values ('4100587464519878','Charlton Ethan','Chase','29-JAN-2021');

insert into Credit_Card
(CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER,OWNER_NAME, MERCHANT_NAME, EXP_DATE)
values ('4100587464513112','Jill Jones','MCU','10-DEC-2022');

insert into Credit_Card
(CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER,OWNER_NAME, MERCHANT_NAME, EXP_DATE)
values ('4100587464511974','Dominique Ashley','Chase','23-OCT-2022');

insert into Credit_Card
(CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER,OWNER_NAME, MERCHANT_NAME, EXP_DATE)
values ('4100587464518774','Mario Mark','TD','13-MAY-2020');

(CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER,OWNER_NAME, MERCHANT_NAME, EXP_DATE)
values ('4100587464516004','Charles Vanny','TD','16-JUL-2021');

SELECT *
FROM CREDIT_CARD;
```

based on these tables:

```sql
--Create Physician Table
CREATE TABLE PHYSICIAN
(
PH_Person_ID    Number(10)  NOT NULL,
Physician_Pager_Number  VarChar2(10)    NULL,
Physician_DEA_Number    VarChar2(11)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PHPersonID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PH_Person_ID),
CONSTRAINT PHPersonID_FK FOREIGN KEY (PH_Person_ID) REFERENCES Person (Person_ID)
);
```

and

```sql
--Create Volunteer Table
CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEER
(
VO_Person_ID    Number(10)   NOT NULL,
Interest_ID     VarChar2(10)    NOT NULL,
Constraint VOPersonID_PK PRIMARY KEY(VO_Person_ID),
Constraint VOPersonID_FK FOREIGN KEY(VO_Person_ID) References Person(Person_ID),
Constraint InterestID_FK FOREIGN KEY(Interest_ID) References Interest(Interest_ID)
);
```

and

```sql
--Create Credit Card Table
CREATE TABLE CREDIT_CARD
(
Credit_Card_Number    Number(16)   NOT NULL,
Owner_Name  VarChar2(30)    NULL,
Merchant_Name   VarChar(30)    NULL,
Exp_Date    Date    NULL,
Constraint CreditCardNumber_FK FOREIGN KEY (Credit_Card_Number) References Patient_Credit_Card (Credit_Card_Number)
);
```

I am getting the same error message as a result for ALL of them:

```
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HMSAADMIN1.PHPERSONID_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

and

```
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HMSAADMIN1.INTERESTID_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

and

```
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HMSAADMIN1.CREDITCARDNUMBER_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

What am I missing that I did not add in? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Seems fairly straight-forward. The foreign key values you're attempting to insert (`PH_Person_ID`, `VO_Person_ID` and `Credit_Card_Number`) do not exist in their reference tables (`Person` and `Patient_Credit_Card`)

Comment: For example, each physician has a PERSON_ID pointing to table PERSON. Did you insert rows into the PERSON table first? If not, of course you will get those errors. If that is not obvious to you, you need a refresher on the meaning of "foreign key".

Comment: I actually inserted this into the person table and it worked and showed me the tables:                                           ```insert into PERSON
(Person_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Middle_Name, Street_Address,
    City, State, Zipcode, Country, Birth_Date, Gender, Phone,
    Email, Is_Patient, Is_Physician, Is_Employee, Is_Volunteer)
values ('12333', 'Victoria', 'Tirado', 'Amanda', '1951 Lane Drive', 'Bronx', 'NY', '10467', 'US', TO_DATE('8/4/1999',
'DD/MM/YYYY'),'F','7188751200', 'heyhey@gmail.com', 'N', 'N', 'N','Y');

Select *
From PERSON;```

Comment: @Phil I am trying to insert them into their own tables. I am testing my tables and inserting information into it. What do I do now?

Comment: That shows you inserted **one** person, with person id - 12333. The first physician in your inserts has id 12123. If there is no person with person id = 12123 in the PERSON table, it doesn't matter what **other** rows you added to that table. Did you, in fact, add enough rows to PERSON to have the proper id's for ALL the INSERT into PHYSICIAN? Etc.

Comment: @mathguy person is its own table, Physician is its own table, volunteer is its own table, and credit card is its own table. I am trying to insert the above information into the separate tables but are you saying that I have to insert something into the person table in order to insert things into their own table?

Comment: Do i have to add in a [WHERE Search_condition ]; option? I am only asking because I am trying to figure out homework but okay @mathguy. I am only asking questions because you guys are the experts.

Answer (score -1):

When you complete to execute insert script, Sql developer will redirect you to another page.
In this page, you will see your all insert codes. You must click ctrl+a and then you must execute this page. Some data may be missed but you can add more